# multiple if statements and a loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I have a logical problem. I will provide pseudo code since the real code isn't all that readable. I want to only enter one of the instructions, and if none of the instructions are reachable I want the function to break out from the loop.

I'm pretty new to programming so any help is appreciated.

edit:  In every iteration I want to only reach one of the conditions. Since there is a loop going on for a longer time I want to be able to reach the same / other instructions for every iteration

```
while(true){
     if(condition){ // Instruction 1
        do stuff
    }else{
        do stuff
    }
    if(condition){ // Instruction 2
        do stuff
    }else{
        do stuff
    }
    if(condition){ // Instruction 3
        do stuff
    }else{
        do stuff
    }

    if(condition){ // Instruction 4
        do stuff
    }else{
        do stuff
    }

    if(none condition){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you wrote doesn't do what you explain it should do

Comment: Whats the point of that loop if you break out of it at first iteration anyway? Edit: Just read your comment under MrWhiteNerdy answer. With that information the loop makes more sense.

Comment: This question can be interpreted in a lot of ways. You should clarify your question more. While(true) loops are dangerous things and can be a massive burden on your CPU if you carelessly throw them into your code. Do make sure the loop can't be infinite. You can probably do this also without the loop but it requires more and specific information on what it is you want to create.

Comment: Edited my answer a bit for further clarifications

Comment: @Amar If, for example, you have successfully done Instruction 1, do you still want to do the `else` of Instruction 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think anyone's got this spot on so far so I'll throw in my understanding of what you're asking.

```
while(true) // keep looping
{
    boolean instructionExecuted = false; // we haven't done an instruction this iteration

    // Instruction 1
    if(condition) {                         
        instructionExecuted = true;
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }

    // Instruction 2
    if(condition && !instructionExecuted) {  // If we've not done an instruction,
                                             // and we can do instruction #2
        instructionExecuted = true;
        //do stuff
    } else if (!instructionExecuted) {       // only do this if we haven't already
                                             // done an instruction
        //do stuff
    }

    // Instruction 3
    if(condition && !instructionExecuted) { // If we've not done an instruction,
        instructionExecuted = true;         // and we can do instruction #3
        //do stuff
    } else if (!instructionExecuted) {      // only do this if we haven't already
                                            // done an instruction
        //do stuff
    }

    //etc.

    if(none condition)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, I'm going to fix my code so it suits ur answer and try this.

Comment: Great. I believe it's what you're after. Let me know if it doesn't match what you need and I'll be happy to try and fix it.

Comment: Ye this worked, thanks for the help, highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bool trigger might be what you are looking for. if you enter any if statements turn the trigger to true.

Comment: what is a *bool trigger*?

Comment: take a look at Andrew's answer below.

Comment: I haven't heard that terminology before. Is it a language specific thing? Flags is a more common terminology IMO

Comment: I've heard both terms. Maybe the word trigger is more used in c#? Either way, I think the term trigger draws a better picture for beginners.

Comment: C# thing eh? Do you have any links that would verify this. Also, a trigger is generally something that happens in response to an event. I haven't heard anyone use it in this context before.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean reachable = false;
while(true){
    if(condition){ // Instruction 1
        do stuff
        reachable = true
    }else{
        do stuff
    }
    if(condition){ // Instruction 2
        do stuff
        reachable = true
    }else{
        do stuff
    }
    if(condition){ // Instruction 3
        do stuff
        reachable = true
    }else{
        do stuff
    }

    if(condition){ // Instruction 4
        do stuff
        reachable = true
    }else{
        do stuff
    }

    if(!reachable){
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making this harder than it has to be. All you need to do is have an if statement with multiple else if statements after it.

Example:

```
if (condition) {
    doStuff();
} else if (condition) {
    doStuff();
} else if (condition) {
    ...
} else {
    break;
}
```

Comment: But then I can't reach the else of each instruction? Or am I missing something

Comment: In your question you stated that you wanted to enter only one of the statements.

Comment: I might have explained it poorly. In every iteration I wan't to only reach one of the conditions. Since there is a loop going on for a longer time I want to be able to reach the same / other instructions for every iteration

Answer (score 0):

well, there are multiple ways to accomplish what you want:

- Introduce a top-level boolean flag `doNotBreak` and set true in if/else blocks execution of which means the loop should not break.
- Check should it break or not by combining conditions using in the loop: `if(condition1 && !condition2 && ..) break;`
- Instead of the last condition, break with condition and inside if/else block where you don't want to break, use `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can check if it is possible to use switch Statements instead of if-else. Example

```
        public static void main(String argv[]) {
          String [] conditions = {"condition_1","condition_2","condition_3","condition_4","xyz"};
          printConditionType(conditions);
        } 
        public static void printConditionType(String [] conditions){
          int i = 0;
          while (i<conditions.length){
             switch (conditions[i]) {
                 case "condition_1":
                    System.out.println("#1");
                    break;
                 case "condition_2":
                    System.out.println("#2");                    
                    break;
                 case "condition_3":
                    System.out.println("#3");                    
                    break;
                 case "condition_4":
                    System.out.println("#4");
                    break;
                 default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid condition:" + conditions[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```